# Buildout and zc.recipe.egg - specifying egg download URL directly?

Tags: python, buildout

zc.recipe.egg allows you to install any egg and its script with buildout.

However, zc.recipe.egg relies on `find-links` and `index` behavior, inherit from setuptools I guess. It would like to take an egg server / HTML for scanning.

What if I just want to point zc.recipe.egg to a egg direct download URL how would I do that? Looks like putting it to find-links is no go.

Comment: any specific egg we are talking about here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the direct egg link in `find-links` works just fine, but you must remember to also pin the version of the egg.

What happens is that the link you provide for the egg is taken into consideration as *one* option. If buildout finds a newer version of the egg elsewhere, it'll ignore the directly linked version still.

Example, no version pin:

```
[buildout]
parts = i18ndude
find-links = http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/i/i18ndude/i18ndude-3.1.3.zip

[i18ndude]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = i18ndude
```

```
$ bin/buildout -N
Installing i18ndude.
Getting distribution for 'i18ndude'.
Got i18ndude 3.2.2.
Generated script '/private/tmp/test/bin/i18ndude'.
$ grep i18ndude- bin/i18ndude
    '/Users/mj/Development/.buildout/eggs/i18ndude-3.2.2-py2.6.egg',
```

With a version pin:

```
[buildout]
parts = i18ndude
find-links = http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/i/i18ndude/i18ndude-3.1.3.zip
versions = versions

[versions]
i18ndude = 3.1.3

[i18ndude]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = i18ndude
```

```
$ bin/buildout -N
Updating i18ndude.
Getting distribution for 'i18ndude'.
Got i18ndude 3.1.3.
Generated script '/private/tmp/test/bin/i18ndude'.
$ grep i18ndude- bin/i18ndude
    '/Users/mj/Development/.buildout/eggs/i18ndude-3.1.3-py2.6.egg',
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in find-links should work. I've done that in the past. You have to make sure the link is of the correct format as any python egg.